# Is it possible to make more than one Pokémon save file?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-sixth-generation

Is there a way to get a second save file in the game Pokemon Y? I got the game for Christmas and want to share the game with my brother, but I can't without deleting my save file because there is only one save file available.

I've heard some things about having a second SD card to do it, would it be possible with multiple SD Cards? If so, any tips on how to get a second one? How do I install it?

Comment: Doesn't X/Y keep the save data on the cartridge itself, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Well after some Google'ing what I gather is the e-shop version saves to the SD card, and the cartridge version saves to the cartridge. [More information](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67450427), but this may not be correct.

Comment: i have pokemon y on sdcard i assume that it have some sort of save file integrated on that file, and each game have some sort of cd-key which makes duplicating it impossible

Comment: @KernelPanic: All of the answers on that page seem to contradict eachother, so I honestly don't know.

Comment: +1 I have my copy on SD card as well, but... when I check the files which have last been modified, their modified last date/time isn't the last date/time I saved my game. Though if the save file is really on the SD card, that'd mean I could also let my sister play Y!

Comment: My guess is, the only way to have multiple saves is by owning the e-shop version, downloading it to 2 different SD cards, and simply swap the SD cards to switch the savegame.

Answer (score 5):

> ### 6 Saving and Erasing Data
>
> You can only keep one saved-game file.
>
> ### 6 Saving and Erasing Data (Notes regarding the downloadable version)
>
> You can copy or move your data to a different SD Card, but you cannot use such data as a backup of your save.

Source: The electronic instruction manual accessible before or during play. You can access it by pressing the Home button, and while you have Pokémon X/Y highlighted choose Manual instead of Open/Resume.

While I have not tried personally, I assume there is some way the game prevents multiple save files.

There may be illegitimate ways to gain a second save file, but these could damage your game and/or save. The easiest way is purchasing a second copy. I recommend getting X so you and your brother can help complete each other's Pokédexes.

Answer (score -4):

Actually, both games (download+cartridge) save to the sd card. In other words, hell yeah you can have two save games!!! You just need a second sd card. Nice and convenient! ;)

Comment: Sadly, that's not true. Pokemon X/Y (and Animal Crossing) stores the save file directly on the cartridge and not on the SD card.